# How to get username or email from onedriveclient sdk c#

Tags: c#, uwp, onedrive, windows-10-universal

How to get username or email from `IOneDriveClient`?

Authentication:

```
string[] scopes = { "onedrive.readwrite" };
IOneDriveClient OneDriveClient = OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(scopes);
await OneDriveClient.AuthenticateAsync();
```

Comment: How to get picture of user account

Comment: @DeviPrasad
// get contact by phone number
async Task<Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Contact> _Get_Contact_ByPhone(string tel)
        {
            var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync(ContactStoreAccessType.AllContactsReadOnly);
            var contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync(tel);
            return contacts.Count > 0 ? contacts.ElementAt(0) : null;
        }

Then use `SmallDisplayPicture` or `LargeDisplayPicture` field for getting stream.
Sorry for the markup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can't get username or email from `IOneDriveClient` directly. But form `IOneDriveClient` we can get `AccessToken`. And when we have `AccessToken`, we can use it with Live Connect Representational State Transfer (REST) API to retrieve user's name.

The REST API to request info about the signed-in user is:

```
GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

For more infomation, see [Requesting info using REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826533.aspx#requesting_info_using_rest).

So in the app, we can use following code to get user's display name:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "onedrive.readwrite" };
var client = OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(scopes) as OneDriveClient;
await client.AuthenticateAsync();
//get the access_token
var AccessToken = client.AuthenticationProvider.CurrentAccountSession.AccessToken;
//REST API to request info about the signed-in user
var uri = new Uri($"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token={AccessToken}");

var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
//user info returnd as JSON
string jsonUserInfo = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
if (jsonUserInfo != null)
{
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonUserInfo);
    string username = json["name"].ToString();
}
```

To get user's email, we need to add `wl.emails` scope in `scopes`. [wl.emails scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243646.aspx#wlemails) enables read access to a user's email addresses. The code may like following:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "onedrive.readwrite", "wl.emails" };
var client = OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(scopes) as OneDriveClient;
await client.AuthenticateAsync();
//get the access_token
var AccessToken = client.AuthenticationProvider.CurrentAccountSession.AccessToken;
//REST API to request info about the signed-in user
var uri = new Uri($"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token={AccessToken}");

var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
//user info returnd as JSON
string jsonUserInfo = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
if (jsonUserInfo != null)
{
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonUserInfo);
    string username = json["name"].ToString();
    string email = json["emails"]["account"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: @DeviPrasad // get contact by phone number async Task<Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Contact> _Get_Contact_ByPhone(string tel) { var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync(ContactStoreAccessType.AllContactsReadOnly); var contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync(tel); return contacts.Count > 0 ? contacts.ElementAt(0) : null; } Then use SmallDisplayPicture or LargeDisplayPicture field for getting stream. Sorry for the markup.